# Android Status Bar covering Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, statusbar, hamburger-menu

I'm having a problem with Status Bar covering Navigation Drawer - I want to hide the Status Bar under the Navigation Drawer, when it's opened. I've seen many posts and other topics with this problem suggesting using:

`<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`

in values\styles.xml, but it doesn't work for me. Would you suggest any solution?

My code:

v21\styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

values\styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds" tools:targetApi="lollipop">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:openDrawer="start">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"></androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"></com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and fragment of code from MainActivity.java, from onCreate method:

```
Window window = getWindow();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

    // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

    // finally change the color
        
    window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
}
```